# Can someone explain the following strange function declarations?

Tags: c++, multithreading, function, function-declaration

```
std::thread f()
{
  void some_function(); // <- here
  return std::thread(some_function);
}

std::thread g()
{
  void some_other_function(int); // <- here
  std::thread t(some_other_function,42);
  return t;
}
```

Comment: I think there may have been an edit conflict… sorry… but I don't see the question either way. Could you at least add a comment to the code as to what you think is strange or missing?

Comment: @Liu: don't let your poor English discourage you from trying to express your question. 1) Practice makes perfect. 2) Right now, we have nothing to answer.

Comment: "void some_other_function(int);  "

Comment: Seens like a function declaration, What's it ?

Comment: Yes, that's what it is. It does the same thing as it would outside the function, except the name is only defined in the scope the declaration is in. Usually you should declare functions in a header file, not the `.cpp` file, much less inside a local scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lines like:

```
void some_function();
```

simply declare a function which will be defined later. Functions don't necessarily have to be declared outside of function scope.

Comment: What I am actually wondering is that it is in an function defintion?

Comment: @Liu: No, it is a *declaration* - it just declares that there is some function named `some_function` that returns `void` and takes no parameters. The definition presumably is somewhere later in the same file.

Comment: Thank you, sorry for my bad c++!

Answer (score 1):

It's just a function declaration, as you thought.  It is common (and recommended) to put function declarations in header files, but this is by no means required.  They may be in function bodies.

Answer (score 1):

Define a function returning a `thread` object:

```
std::thread f()
{
```

Declare an `extern` function with no arguments returning `void` (usually this is not done in local scope, but it is valid):

```
void some_function();
```

Start a thread executing that function, and return a handle to it:

```
return std::thread(some_function);
}
```

Same deal as before:

```
std::thread g()
{
void some_other_function(int);
```

But this is not valid. You can't make a copy of a thread, so technically it is not OK to make a local `thread` object and then return it. I'd be surprised if this compiled, but if it does, it might break when you build for the debugger.

```
std::thread t(some_other_function,42);
return t;
}
```

This would work, though:

```
return std::move( t );
```